# Inconsistent paddings on the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

It seems that icons and text menu items on a Toolbar take different paddings

[image]

Google doesn't seem to implement their design specification. I think icons take 12dp but text menu items take just 8dp. What's the right way to give text menu items additional padding so that they match icons' paddings?

What is the canonical approach to handling this inconsistency?

Thanks

Comment: Icon != text. Actually both icon and text menu items are squares. And dimensions of that squares are the same. And in design specs I found only information about metrics and keylines for icon menu item (https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size), but not for text. Can you please point to that part of design specs you think Google doesn't seem to implement?

Comment: Also, you can't make menu item square larger - fixed height, you can't create rect instead of square - it will look weird. The only way you will be able to change paddings - change font size. But don't you mind that vertical padding for text is greater that horizontal? You will not be able to create text menu item, that will exactly look like icon menu item.